# Обрезанный фон в верстке

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Требуется, чтобы эта фоновая картинка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

отображалась во весь свой размер, но вместо этого, она почему то обрезается

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.section {
  padding: 80px 0;
}

.section_header {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 950px;
  margin: 0 auto 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.section_title {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 27px;
  color: black;
}

.section_title:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 3px;
  margin: 30px auto 0;
  background-color: #a05e2d;
}

.section_text {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #f6950a;
}

.section--supply {
  background: url("../image/back2.jpeg") center no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<section class="section  section--supply">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="section_header">
      <h2 class="section_title">Unique supply</h2>
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: ну конечно обрезанный - вы же сами написали cover то есть обрезать фон так что бы вместился

Answer (score 0):

Ну например вот так:

```css
html,body { width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; background: black;  }

.section {
  padding: 80px 0 ;
 }

 .section_header {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 950px;

  margin: 0 auto 50px;

  text-align: center;
 }

 .section_title {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 27px;
  color: black;

 } 

 .section_title:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 3px;
  margin: 0px auto 0;

  background-color: #a05e2d;
  
 }

 .section_text {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #f6950a;

 }

.section--supply {
  height: 100%;
  background: url("https://sun9-54.userapi.com/Ybexrl6fNZpYzLtatZtQCsxj38B--_LAxqL6FA/oMTCtIUVIr0.jpg") center no-repeat;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
 }
```

```html
<section class="section  section--supply">
 <div class="container">

  <div class="section_header">
   <h2 class="section_title">Unique supply</h2>
  </div>

 </div>
</section>
```

Либо свойство **background-size** поменять на **contain**

Comment: получается так https://wampi.ru/image/Rdi3JGr